# SKScene with bindings in a SpriteView

Tags: swiftui, sprite-kit, spriteview

I've created a SpriteKit Scene file and the corresponding `SKScene` object. That scene object includes an `@Binding` property.

When I use `SpriteView` in my SwiftUI file, I can't figure out how to initialize the scene so that it loads from the sks file and also assigns a binding.

I'm wanting something like this:

```swift
class MyScene: SKScene {
    @Binding var foo: CGFloat

    init(foo: Binding<CGFloat>) {
      _foo = foo
      super.init(fileNamed: "MyScene")
    }
}
```

That doesn't work though because `init(fileNamed:)` is a convenience initializer, not a designated initializer.

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: If I had a minimal example I wouldn't have the question.  SKScene doesn't have a designated initializer that accepts a file, it's just a convenience, so I can't subclass it.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround using `ObservableObject` to subscribe to `foo`. I pass a fileName so I have an excuse to invoke my convenience initializer.

```
class MyScene: SKScene, ObservableObject {
    @Published var foo: CGFloat = 0

    convenience init(fileName: String) {
      self.init(fileNamed: fileName)!
    }
}
```

And then hold a reference to it on your view (or elsewhere).

```
struct MyView: View {

    @ObservedObject var scene = MyScene(fileName: "MyScene")

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            FooView($scene.foo)
            SpriteView(scene: scene)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not what I'm looking for.  Inside the SKScene I need an `@Binding`, not an `@Published`.  The data is being sent into the scene from `@State` elsewhere.

Comment: Have a look at my solution: https://github.com/alexpilugin/ap-swiftui-spriteview-ios14